# US visa renewal, not asked for documents

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, applications

Just renewed my expired 10 year US visa but the consular officer didn’t not ask for my documents. They kept my passport and gave me a piece of paper with information on how I would get the passport and visa returned. Should I be concerned that all my paperwork was not submitted with the application?

Comment: I would be over the moon. What makes you worried?

Comment: Starting to wonder if I was supposed to just hand all the paperwork in with the application. Are consular officers supposed to ask for your supporting documents? Worried because flying in couple of weeks and can’t afford much delay on visa.

Comment: Eh? It would be unusual if you were asked for documents.

Comment: Unusual for them to ask (i.e. should just voluntarily hand in without being asked) or unusual that they would ask for anything at all? Guidance was to have documents showing ties to home country and intention to return.

Comment: So worried for nothing as usual. Status changed to issued this morning.